# Excel cell referencing a variable sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a tab for every month's worth of data, and then I have a summary that references the current month's sheet.  Is there any way I can put "April 2015" (this would be the name of the sheet) in cell A1, and then have formulas like:

> =COUNTIFS('(String in A1)'!$I$10:$I$149,B4,'(String in A1)'!$L10:$L149,"")

That way I'd only have to edit the 1 cell and I'd know all the references are correct whereas if one of the formulas don't get replaced, I'd be referring to a month behind on one random cell and likely never even know.

Seems like that should be very simple, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful to preserve those **single quotes:**

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!$I$10:$I$149"),B4,INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "'!$L10:$L149"),"")
```

Comment: May be important to note that the cell range addresses are text and will not change when copied or filled to a new location. As text, the absolute *$* designations become redundant although they may help as a visual reference.